# Transact SQL result of query used in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to get the table name to query from a table.

```
var tableName = "select tableName from tableList where type='A';"
```

Then subsequently use that table name in another query.

```
"select * from" + tableName
```

Transact SQL/stored procedures are new to me in general so any help would be appreciated. I didn't design the database and unfortunately can't really change it to be a better design as much as I would love to!

My question is - is this possible from one stored procedure and if so can anyone mock up how I'd do it.
Or if there are any better ways anyone can think of (bar redesigning the database!)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe via dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @String AS VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @TableName AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Results AS VARCHAR(8000)

SET @TableName = (select top 1 tableName from tableList where type='A')
SET @String = 'Select * from ' + @TableName 
SET @Results = @String + @TableName

EXEC @Results
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `exec`as @kevchadders suggested or you can use `sp_executesql`, read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for an excellent explantion on dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly write

```
select * from (select tableName from tableList where type='A') X
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use dynamic SQL to achieve that. 
Basically, you execute your query using sp_executesql or exec, and store the result to a, kinda, staging table to be processed further:

```
declare @sql = varchar(8000);
select @sql = 'insert into resulttbl select * from ' + @tableName;
exec sp_executesql(@sql);
-- further process using resulttbl
```

Or

```
insert into resulttbl 
exec ('select * from ' + @tableName);
-- further process using resulttbl
```

Anyway, you should read the following article for a better explanation: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Why the staging table? You don't need to do this when you use `sp_executeql`.
And why is this staging table no temp table (name begins w/ a #)?

Comment: @Ocaso Protal: I assume OP will use the result on the subsequent query

Comment: That's why you use sp_executesql, there you have the @params parameter to pass and get back parameters. Works like a charm (but sometimes it looks confusing), I had to use sp_executesql very often. But nonetheless a temp-table is most of the time the better solution to store intermediate results.